# Manage Connection in Mongoose across Modules

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a Node Module which will perform some databasebase queries using mongoose. What I want is to access the mongoose connection variable across the module  which is created in the main application. I have read that Mongoose is a singleton object to I guess it should work but it isn't working at all. ANy help will be appreciated

Comment: The mongoose connection variable? Do you mean the URI, or the object that the connection instantiates?

Comment: The  connection object.  I want to access the database like as if I am in the same module

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand. Maybe you could add some code?

Comment: Let me explain you. I am creating a node module which will authenticate users in the database. So I want some to access the database from the model. Maybe I can send a connection object or some other logic. But I don't want the uri string to be passed